# Alterar valor de todos ssearch em um requisição do Jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables, get, http-request

Estou usando os métodos

`$(_table)
    .DataTable()
    .column(colIdx)
    .search(text)
    .draw();`

para realizar filtros na minha Datatable. Porém, para diminuir o número de requisições, realizo esta função apenas quando aperto a tecla "ENTER" em uma caixa de texto passando, desta forma, o valor do colIdx e o valor desta caixa de texto para o DataTable. Acontece que, ao alterar o valor de uma caixa de texto e enviar uma nova requisição passando outro input (dando ENTER em outro input), o valor dos sSeach referente ao primeiro input de valor alterado permanecem os mesmos. Haveria alguma forma de pegar o valor de todos os inputs e alterar o valor de todos os sSeach em uma única requisição?

Segue um exemplo dos parâmetros sSearch das requisições:

--AO ALTERAR O VALOR DO INPUT E APERTAR ENTER

```
sSearch_0:teste
sSearch_1:abcd
```

--AO ALTERAR O VALOR DO INPUT REFERENTE AO sSEACH_0 e sSerach_1 E DAR ENTER NO INPUT REFERENTE AO sSERACH_1

```
sSearch_0:teste
sSearch_1:wxyz
```

Como o exemplo mostra, o valor do sSeach_0 não mudou mesmo com valor do input ter sido alterado.

Haveria alguma forma de pegar o valor de todos os inputs e alterar o valor de todos os sSeach em uma única requisição?

Comment: Você está usando algum plugin no seu jquery?

Comment: @DiegoMoreno nenhum plugin além do próprio jquery